# Redux Store & third party data structures

Tags: javascript, redux

*This is a hacky-ish question about mixing redux with 3rd party libraries. I'm well aware that this is contrary to the Redux guides. It's mostly for discussion and exploration - I also didn't want to pollute their Github issues ;)*

**The third party data**
We're using a relational and immutable data structure module to store our application data. In a nutshell, the module works a little like a relational database:

- It exposes Tables
- Tables contain the application data
- Tables have 4 methods: get, post, put, delete
- Data objects dynamically reference each other by index/primary key

**Current Redux Store structure**
Since we're using Redux, we initially chose NOT to expose the tables directly, since they contain methods. We instead expose the result of `Table.get();`, which returns an array of it's data objects.

So our reducers "update state" by working with the 3rd party module. The heavy-lifting is done by the 3rd party, the reducers basically always return `Table.get();`.
Our store looks something like this:

```
// the application data (built by relational-json)
var appDB = {
    People: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    },
    Organization: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    },
    Address: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    }
};

// example Reducer
store = createStore(combineReducers({
    Person: function personReducer(state, action) {
        "use strict";

        switch (action.type) {
            case "UPDATE_PERSON_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_PERSON": {
                appDB.Person.put(action.data, "Person");

                return appDB.Person.get();
            }

            case "CREATE_PERSON": {
                appDB.Person.post(action.data, "Person");

                return appDB.Person.get();
            }

            default: {
                return appDB.Person.get();
            }
        }
    },
    Organization: function personReducer(state, action) {
        "use strict";

        switch (action.type) {
            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Organization.put(action.data, "Organization");

                return appDB.Organization.get();
            }

            case "CREATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Organization.post(action.data, "Organization");

                return appDB.Organization.get();
            }

            default: {
                return appDB.Organization.get();
            }
        }
    },
    Address: function personReducer(state, action) {
        "use strict";

        switch (action.type) {
            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Address.put(action.data, "Address");

                return appDB.Address.get();
            }

            case "CREATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Address.post(action.data, "Address");

                return appDB.Address.get();
            }

            default: {
                return appDB.Address.get();
            }
        }
    }
}));


// resulting initial state looks like:
var state = {
    Person: [],
    Organization: [],
    Address: []
};
```

Our actual setup looks like above, but with close to 100 reducers. Most of the reducers are extremely identical, too. Their only changes are often the type of the action and the Table to update.

**THE QUESTION**

**Alternative Store structure?**
We're contemplating having a single reducer to handle the 3rd party data, and exposing the "Tables".get() in the Store structure. Our store would then have a much simpler structure (*and much fewer reducers*), and look something like:

```
// the application data (built by relational-json)
var appDB = {
    People: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    },
    Organization: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    },
    Address: {
        get: function() {},
        post: function() {},
        put: function() {},
        delete: function() {}
    }
};

// example Reducer
store = createStore(combineReducers({
    appDB: function dbReducer(state, action) {
        "use strict";

        switch (action.type) {
            case "UPDATE_PERSON_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_PERSON": {
                appDB.Person.put(action.data, "Person");
                break;
            }

            case "CREATE_PERSON": {
                appDB.Person.post(action.data, "Person");
                break;
            }

            case "UPDATE_ORGANIZATION_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_ORGANIZATION": {
                appDB.Organization.put(action.data, "Organization");
                break;
            }

            case "CREATE_ORGANIZATION": {
                appDB.Organization.post(action.data, "Organization");
                break;
            }

            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS_LIST":
            case "UPDATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Address.put(action.data, "Address");
                break;
            }

            case "CREATE_ADDRESS": {
                appDB.Address.post(action.data, "Address");
                break;
            }

            default: {
                break;
            }
        }

        return Object.keys(appDB).reduce(function(obj, key) {
            obj[key] = appDB[key].get;

            return obj;
        }, {})
    }
}));


// resulting initial state looks like:
var state = {
    appDB: {
        People: function get() {},
        Organization: function get() {},
        Address: function get() {}
    }
};
```

Where things conflict is that `apis.apiX` would be an object of methods mentioned above (get). The data isn't directly exposed, it has to be exposed by using `Table.get();`

This doesn't cause a problem in our case since we get data by using selectors (*reselect*), and they know when the data has changed, even if they have to go through `Table.get();`

Where I'm uneasy/unsure is for anything else expected or done by Redux.   Would such a structure break things?

Comment: Very interesting.  What library are you using for that?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these options are opposite to how Redux apps work because you rely on data mutations rather than return new objects.

While technically you can mutate data with Redux I think it's more trouble than it's worth in this scenario because you don't really get benefits of Redux. For example, the views can't redraw efficiently because mutations make it impossible to tell from a glance which data has changed.

This is why I suggest you to not use Redux if you want to treat a specific client-side DB as the source of truth. Redux only works well if *it* is the source of truth. So just use the DB directly and/or build an abstraction around it that better fits what you are trying to do.

Comment: relational-json is also immutable. So any "put" operation returns a new object, using a combination of the old and new values. A post, put or delete operation uses a new array to present the data collection. So everytime data is modified, the containing array (and modified object(s)) are re-created.
The reason why I felt it could work with redux was precisely because it doesn't mutate data. (sorry if that wasn't clearly stated)

In other words, if I Table.get(), then Table.post();, then Table.get(); the two returned values from get(); don't reference the same array.

Comment: The `Table` itself is a mutable object. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `put()` without using return value and later call `get()` to have something else. It may use Immutable inside, but the `Table` contract is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Redux doesn't care what your store looks like. It's an abstraction. You decide how it looks. You also decide how actions affect it with reducers. Deciding to expose methods and/or data is irrelevant honestly. Nothing will *break* as long as you stick with your design decisions. The only thing I would be wary of is whether or not your application state is truly immutable by exposing methods rather than only data.

Besides that, knowing that your application state is reflected by third-party methods implies you develop components with that in mind. It may not be the agreed upon ideal example, but that doesn't mean you can't do it. That's my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm).  It provides a similar "model"-like API around Redux-style immutable reducers.  Still new, but seems pretty useful so far.